# Why did Pruitt believe that he had seen an angel?

Tags: midnight-mass-2021

When Monsignor Pruitt went to Jerusalem, he wandered off in the desert and encountered a sort of being or creature.

> The being that he met *looked* like a stereotypical image of a demon, complete with leathery bat wings. It *acted* like a typical fantasy vampire, attacking the Monsignor and drinking his blood. Furthermore, it lacked characteristics that angels tended to exhibit in the Christian Bible (such as being capable of speech, say) and had traits that they emphatically did *not* have, such as being afraid of sunlight or needing help to be transported to a new place.

It seems that a logical reaction for a highly religious Catholic versed in theology would be that they had been attacked by a demon and saved by the grace of God. A less religious person would probably assume that they had been the victim of a vampire attack or something of the sort (which would be rather close to the truth).

However, the good priest instead concluded that the being was an angel who had saved him in order that he might bring eternal life to his flock. It was not simply that he tried to make the best of the situation in the belief that divine providence was guiding his actions: he actually thought that it was an angel. While he had previously had dementia, his de-aging apparently eliminated it. As such, why did he reach this conclusion?

Comment: It may take a while to get an answer, this was only released (and only in the US) three days ago.

Answer (score 5):

*Given how recently the show aired, this answer is entirely from memory. As more resources become available, hopefully I'll have time to (or someone else can) edit in specific relevant clips, quotes, and stills from the show.*

---

Pruitt himself says a few things to explain why he believed the creature to be an angel. Further, I believe it helps to take a wider view of the show's commentary on religion to understand why the character of Pruitt was written to believe that something so stereotypically evil was actually divine.

#### What Pruitt says

**It had a halo.** In the flashback to the cave, he remembers seeing a halo around the creature's head. [In Christian iconography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_(religious_iconography)#In_Christian_art), a halo indicates the divine nature of an individual, or that they have divine favor. Note that we don't know if there actually *was* a halo -- this is Pruitt's flashback, so it's how he is remembering it.

[image: The creature in a cave with a halo]

**It talked to him.** While you're correct that we don't hear the creature speak in the show, Pruitt indicates that *he* hears it speak. He never indicates what it tells him, so we can only speculate that it might have explained it's origins or intentions to him. Also, if we assume that the creature generally follows vampire lore, it's possible that it [hypnotized](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Hypnotic+Powers) Pruitt, though this is rather an unsatisfying explanation.

**Angels are scary.** Pruitt repeats this several times. He was afraid of the creature -- as were most of those in the Bible who saw angels, he explains. It's also interesting to note (though not addressed in the show) that no one in the Bible is described as having an in-person encounter with a demon or the devil aside from [Jesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temptation_of_Christ) and [Eve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_of_man). In neither of these examples did the devil pretend to be an angel.

**"By their fruits ye shall know them".** This is a quote from the Bible, in [Matthew 7:20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%207%3A16-20&version=KJV). This quote (or other, similar ones -- I don't recall specifically) are used by Pruitt and Bev to explain how something so scary could be from God: The creature's intervention results in miracles, healing, and a religious revival on the island. These "fruits" are good, therefore the source must also be good.

#### Commentary on religious fanaticism

Ultimately, none of this is enough to explain Pruitt's interpretation of the creature as an angel. But there are three themes in the show that point to how Pruitt was able to delude himself into believing this.

**Do the ends justify the means?** On a number of occasions, something bad happens, and someone explains how it's actually good. This starts with things that happen: Riley causing a young woman's death at the start of the show is "good" because it brought him back to the island to meet Pruitt. Erin's pregnancy is "good" because it gives her a reason to live and the determination to leave her abusive husband. The accident which caused Leeza to be paralyzed is "good" because it allowed for the "miracle" which jump-started the island's religious revival.

Inevitably, this leads to justifying choices based on their results:

> Joe Coolie's death is good because it showed Pruitt that his conscience is free. Erin's house going up in a blaze is good because it fulfills the prophecy of Revelation.

This, of course, leads to the epic conclusion, where "the ends justify the means" is exposed as fraud:

> Self-inflicted death by rat poison is "good" because it allows you to be resurrected with "angelic" powers and eternal life.

The commentary here is that Pruitt is so fanatical, and so committed to his vision of resurrection, that any negative side effects can be ignored; it looks evil, but results in good, so it must be good. There's a tension here between Pruitt and Bev -- his faith is fervent and he truly can't see the evil he's dealing with until the end. Bev sees the evil, but doesn't care -- she's happy to have a tool to implement her vision of religion on the islanders.

**Is faith just wishful thinking?**  Throughout the show, the faithful are shown to have an uncanny ability to ignore something bad they see because of something good they are hoping for. Riley's mother ignores his alcoholism, murder, and jail time, because she is reunited with him. Pruitt ignores Bev's favoritism, manipulation, and vindictiveness because she supports his vision. And again in the epic conclusion:

> The islanders ignore the death, murder, and bloodshed in the titular Midnight Mass because they want the resurrection and eternal life that their priest has promised. He, of course, is horrified at this point because he has *mostly* managed to enjoy his newfound abilities without murder, and in his vision, everyone else will do the same (which is why he wanted everyone to stay in the church so he could orient them).

Not only do the religious fanatics believe that the ends justify the means, but they don't even need to *see* the ends -- their faith that it's inevitable is enough.

**Is religion just an answer to the fear of oblivion?** The conversation between Erin and Riley where they discuss what happens when they die is the centerpiece of the show. Riley describes entering oblivion with neither fear nor anticipation -- it is something that will happen, inevitably. He describes the naturalistic process as something transcendent, but not mystical.

In contrast, Pruitt is terrified of oblivion. When he encounters the creature, he is nearing the end of his life. The creature "saves" him from oblivion, giving him eternal life, and giving him the opportunity to fix some mistakes from his past. Rather than confronting and reconciling with his fear of oblivion so that he can look critically at the "angel," he ignores the creature's evil nature because of the promise of salvation from oblivion.

Comment: That is an interesting perspective. I think the first and third points are quite strong: if the vampire is bringing about miraculous healing and (seems to) have a halo, that might let someone sufficiently desperate to believe that they have been saved by divine providence believe that it was an angel. After all, a religious Catholic would also be aware that "demons with bat wings and ugly faces" is somewhat more pop culture than Catholic theology, and they would not assume that God would only send angels in one particular way.

Comment: I interpreted the show rather differently, though. To me, it does not seem to be taking potshots at religion, but rather at fanaticism. To me, that is clear in how it juxtaposes Leeza, Erin, and the sheriff with the majority of the islanders. For instance, in the case of Erin, her feelings toward her pregnancy are not dismissed by the plot, and it is not consider negative at all. The show does not contradict her assertion: that her desire to be a better mother than her own mother led her to turn her life around.

Comment: In fact, ultimately, Erin (the "believer'), not Riley, is allowed to have the last line on eschatology (from a perspective that could be considered atheist if one squints a bit, but seems more pantheistic to me) in the show, accompanied by stirring violins, so one might even think that the show is outright taking her side. Aside from her, though, we also have Leeza. She is clearly one of the most religious of the islanders--she is the only one who turns up for Mass consistently--but she is also one of those who most firmly rejects the Midnight Mass, even in the face of her parents' pressure.

Comment: Finally, we have the sheriff. He is an observant Muslim, and his faith leads him not to accept the miracles that he sees happening around him, but to *reject* them in favor of naturalistic explanations. It's his less-religious son who ultimately ends up accepting the offer of vampirization. The show ends with him somewhat triumphantly doing the Fajr prayer with his son as the morning sun dawns on the end of the vampiric menace.

Comment: @Adamant it certainly is critical of fanaticism -- I think the question it leaves for viewers is whether non-fanatical religion is worth the risk of fanaticism. I'll edit my answer a bit to leave this more open-ended. Your comment on what a demon looks like reminds me of [Childhood's End](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Childhood%27s_End), which also has the interesting parallel in terms of who survives in the end.